# Relationship set between table and mapping table to use joins

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have two tables: a "Module" table and a "StaffModule" table. I want to display a list of modules by which staff are present on the staffmodule mapping table.

I've tried

```
from Module join Staffmodule sm with ID = sm.MID
```

with no luck, I get the following error

> Path Expected for join!

However, I thought I had the correct join too allow this, but this is obviously not the case. Can any one help?

StaffModule HBM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 26, 2010 9:50:23 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Hibernate.Staffmodule" schema="WALK" table="STAFFMODULE">
    <composite-id class="Hibernate.StaffmoduleId" name="id">
        <key-many-to-one name="mid" class="Hibernate.Module">
            <column name="MID"/>
        </key-many-to-one>
      <key-property name="staffid" type="int">
        <column name="STAFFID"/>
      </key-property>
    </composite-id>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and Module.HBM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 26, 2010 9:50:23 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="Hibernate.Module" schema="WALK" table="MODULE">
    <id name="id" type="int">
      <column name="ID"/>
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="modulename" type="string">
      <column length="50" name="MODULENAME"/>
    </property>
    <property name="teacherid" type="int">
      <column name="TEACHERID" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
  </class>
```